# Get count of duplicates column value in sharepoint list

Tags: caml-query

Is there a way to find out the count of duplicates column values in sharepoint list using caml query? if yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!

You can pass the column value in `<where>` and it will return all matching value in collection.

To get count you can use `collection.count()`

Example:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Title' />
     <Value Type='Text'>India</Value>
  </Eq>
```

This will return all items having title value India in collection and get count of it.

Full code:

```
SPList spList = spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("CountryList"); 
if (spList != null) 
{ 
   SPQuery qry = new SPQuery(); 
   qry.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>India</Value></Eq></Where>"; 
   qry.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Title' />"; 
   SPListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(qry); 
   int count= listItems.Count;
}
```

Comment: most of the values in the list column are repeating, how will you implement this then ??

Comment: Ref this link to get only distinct values from column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560550/what-is-the-best-way-to-retrieve-distinct-unique-values-using-spquery